# Workaround for Chrome arc path fill bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas

EDIT: This bug was fixed in version 38.

A recent version of Chrome introduced an issue in an application I maintain. I'm not sure if this is one of those weird "seems wrong but is actually correct" issues or if it's an honest-to-god bug, but it only presents in recent versions of Chrome (it started happening about a month ago, I'm not sure exactly which version introduced it)

The bug presents when using the context fill() method on certain paths that are drawn using the context arc() method. Rather than drawing a filled arc, what is filled is an oddly-shaped polygon.

Here's a demonstration of what I mean -- the shape in the upper right should be a filled arc:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('cvs').getContext('2d');

// draw stroked arc 
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI/2);
ctx.lineTo(125, 125);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

// draw filled arc
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(225, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI/2);
ctx.lineTo(275, 125);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
   
// draw stroked triangle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(125, 225);
ctx.lineTo(75, 275);
ctx.lineTo(125, 275);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();

// draw filled triangle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(275, 225);
ctx.lineTo(225, 275);
ctx.lineTo(275, 275);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<div><canvas id="cvs" width="300" height="300" style="border: solid black 1px"></canvas></div>
```

My question is this: is there a workaround for this issue? Preferably one that doesn't require me to write my own filled-arc renderer.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? Do not see any problem here - this is what I'm getting http://oi61.tinypic.com/23wvt2.jpg

Comment: Same as Cheery here on FF31 (without the border though).

Comment: I've seen the bug occur in Chrome 37.0.2062.124 for Windows, as well as Chrome 37.0.2062.117 for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do see this bug on Chrome 37.0.2062.124 on OS X. This may or may not be related to the bug described [here](http://blog.greaterthanzero.com/post/98518366297/a-google-chrome-37-canvas-bug-that-affects-certain-flot), which is supposedly to be fixed in Chrome 38.

As a workaround, rotating a few degrees and immediately rotating it back before filling the arc seems to work.

```
// draw filled arc
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(225, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI/2);
ctx.lineTo(275, 125);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.rotate(1*Math.PI/180); // Rotate 1 degree
ctx.rotate(-1*Math.PI/180); // Reverse rotation
ctx.fill();
```

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/ejacpd1w/1/